# How To: Calculate The Σ / A of Pascal's Triangle To Base 111

Tags: binomial-coefficients, triangles, integers

How would I calculate the sum or area of all the numbers in Pascal's Triangle stopping at row 111?

Would I refer to this as the sum? Or the area (A) within the triangle?

Also, how would I create a graphical image of Pascal's Triangle in Base 111? Like this
[Pascal's Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ormrd.png) and how do I express a number that is within the row 111?

I have invested hours of research into these questions.  The mathematical literature sends me in an infinite rabbit hole of confusion.  I tend to struggle with basics.

Thank you for your knowledge if you've shared some with me.

Comment: Since the sum of the numbers in the $n$-th row is $2^n$, and the sum of the numbers in the first $n$ rows is $[2^{(n+1)} - 2]$, are you asking how to convert $[2^{(n+1)} - 2]$ from base $(10)$ to base $(111)$?

Comment: I guess i am asking what is the sum of all 111 rows and each of the individual row totals.  This answer will give me full scope of thy project.  If I could see 111 rows in an image that would be ideal.

Comment: Clarifications requested: [1] "...If I could see 111 rows in an image..." : What image? [2] "...what is the sum of all 111 rows" : All 111 rows ??  Pascal's triangle has an **infinite** number of rows.  [3] Beyond points [1] and [2] above, since my previous comment enumerates each of the 1st 111 rows, and the sum of the 1st 111 rows, is your *actual* question, (whatever that may be) answered?

Comment: Base $16$ uses $16$ digits $0,1,2,3\ldots,A,B,C,D,E,F$. Base $111$ needs $111$ differents digits. Is this what you really want?

Comment: Yes Base 111 is what I want.  I will go over all this information soon.  Trying to communicate as best as I can here.

Comment: My use case; I am using Pascal's Triangle to process data in my algorithm called 0rcan0mic.  There are eight layers of filtration 8 = ∞ So now, thinking creatively I need to get the data into my computer network by people filling out a form and confirming subscription.  Fine.  Now Pascal's Triangle has been in my mind to be used to sort data into targeted segments.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the formula for calculating the sum of the numbers in row $n$ is $2^n$, the sum of all numbers up to a certain point is the sum of the first $n$ $2^n$ numbers, or in other case, $$2^{n+1} -1$$ In your case with the row being up to 111, the steps to answer this question is:

Step 1: Substitute $n$ with 111 $$2^{111+1} -1$$

Step 2: Use a calculator to calculate the expression because the product is *very* large.

The answer is $$5.192296858... * 10^{33}$$

Remember to calculate the "Area" of a pascal triangle up to base $n$ is $2^{n+1} -1$ :)